# Force div into left column

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with the following

**css:**

```
  #container {
  column-count:2;
  }
```

Inside the container div there are several other divs as shown by the

**html**

```
 <div id="container">
 <div id="box1"></div>
 <div id="box2"></div>
 <div id="box3"></div>
 </div>
```

Is there any way to force "box2", for instance, into the left column.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Float:left or display:inline-block?

Comment: I tried float: left but it doesn't seem to do anything? I'll try inline block and get back to you. Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: This is a generic example, my actual situation involves a container with about 10 divs inside a container and I would like 1 to specifically be on the left but it isn't at the moment

Comment: The div is currently displayed as inline-block and its not helping :/

Comment: wait a bit..uploading live example.

Comment: But according to column-count:2; 10 div will be in 2 column. can i remove that css or container class?

Comment: No, there isn't. You may have to re-think your approach. If you don't want the layout required by column count you will either have to restructure your HTML or change layout methods. This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: @Jack check this one..you need this ? https://jsfiddle.net/mp9030my/

Comment: Okay.. i've checked my site... there are 7 divs inside the container and I would like the 3rd to be on the left but at the moment it appears at the top of the second column as opposed to the bottom of the  first column (where I want it to go)... all of the divs are different heights (not sure if this helps)

Comment: Okay thank you very much Leo the Lion and Paulie_D... i think I can use your last fiddle to help me

Comment: My pleasure..but let me know if this helps you so i can post as answer. And if any issue then feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thanks.. ill try it now and get back to you via this post

Comment: Still unresolved :( floating the differently sized divs causes more problems than it solves.. thanks anyway leo the lion

Comment: After altering the order of the divs and then floating left as suggested by Leo the Lion... it works as intended... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css script:

```
#box2{
float:left;
display:block;}
```

This should work .

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code (example in codepen : http://codepen.io/dws/pen/EyALrp ):

```
#container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}
#box1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
}
#box2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
}

#box3 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    box-ordinal-group: 3;
}
```